# VFPOleDb schema returned but no results in C#

Tags: c#, oledb, visual-foxpro

I'm at the end of my rope on this issue.  Trying to connect to a FoxPro directory hosted locally, using the [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839) with the following code:

```
using (var con = new OleDbConnection(@"Data Source=C:\FoxDB;Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from order", con))
    {               
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(dr["ord_id"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Executing the code does not throw an exception, but there are zero rows returned.  The schema is discovered and returned, as it has 72 fields present when I examine the data reader (I've done the same with data tables, data sets, data adapters, etc.  All return the schema, but zero results).

Building an SSIS package to access the same table and pull into a MSSQL database results in 3,828 records being pulled in.  `order.dbf` on disk is 884kb which seems to jive with the SSIS results I've pulled in.

I've tried adding `Collation Sequence` to the connection string, both `Machine` and `General` to no effect.

Please tell me there's something obvious I'm missing!

UPDATE: So apparently there's something that I just don't understand about FoxPro.  If I change the command type to `CommandType.TableDirect` and switch the command text to just be `order`, it returns all the rows.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not with Foxpro, testing with the same exact code, I can get the result (created a free test table in c:\FoxDb). Ensure that you are using the latest VFPOLEDB driver. It looks like the problem lies within your table.

BTW, order is a keyword, you better write it as:

```
"select * from [order]"
```

although it would work as you did (VFP is forgiving in that regard). The problem might also lie in collation sequence you have used (I never use collation sequences other than machine, they are problematic in Turkish, I expect the same in some other languages).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Machine and General collations yielded the same thing.  Interestingly, I can select from _certain_ tables, but not others.  Also, the tables that I can't select from... if I switch the `CommandText` property to just `order` and modify `CommandType` to `CommandType.TableDirect`, I can get all the rows.  That doesn't do me a lot of good, because I need a where clause, but I thought it was interesting.  Oh, and the version on vfpoledb.dll is 9.0.00.5815, which I think is the latest.  Also, tried to upvote you, but I don't have the reputation, sorry.

Comment: The final version of VFP is 7423, so there may be a later version of the driver.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor, AFAIK latest is 9.0.00.5815. Where I can I find 7423? <br>
If the contents are not a secret, can you zip and send that table (dbf + cdx and fpt if any - I assume it is a free table). If you would email to,  cetin dot basoz at deu dot edu dot tr

Comment: I don't think there is a 7423, latest seems to be 5815 from everything I can find online.  Actually, the table is part of a .dbc... and sadly I can't send it, it's client proprietary data and I don't have authorization to release. :/  Thanks anyway.